Problem MapFragment and map_id Jetpack Compose
I'm trying to get the map I have done on Google Plateform to my android application via Jetpack Compose, but the thing is that for some reasons, I can't retrieve it. This is my code:
@Preview
@Composable
fun MapScreen(mapViewModel: MapViewModel = MapViewModel()) {
    val googleMap by mapViewModel.googleMapStateFlow.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        mapViewModel.temp()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            Text("Map is ready!")

        } else {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
    //GoogleMap(modifier = Modifier.testTag("mapScreen"))

}

class MapViewModel : androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel() {
    private var _googleMapStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<GoogleMap?>(null)
    val googleMapStateFlow: StateFlow<GoogleMap?> = _googleMapStateFlow

    fun temp() {
        var mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(GoogleMapOptions().mapId("MAP_ID"))
        mapFragment.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            _googleMapStateFlow.value = googleMap

        }
    }
}

I suppose it has something to do with how I handle the mapFragment, but I can't see the problem
I try to put logs to see where was the problem. It's in getMapAsync, but can't see how to fix it.
I have also try other ids, but still have the same problem

You should probably use the Google Map compose library and not the views version. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose
